# Why we assume henselian ring is local?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, hensels-lemma

Henselian ring is defined as **local ring** in which hensel lemma holds.
Why do we assume local ring?

What is wrong with the definition that 'henselian ring is defined as hensel lemma holds' ?

Comment: Well for Hensel's lemma you reduce someting w.r.t. a maximal ideal. If a ring is not local, you have several maximal ideals. So which one do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of Hensel's lemma I'm familiar with says that in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, if you have a simple root of a polynomial mod the maximal ideal then it lifts to a simple root. How would you generalize this if there is more than one maximal ideal?

Comment: In Silverman's ' the arithmetic of elliptic curves' , ring is not supposed to be local ring. The lemma is stated with ring R that is complete with respect to some ideal $I$.

Comment: Let A be a ring which is complete with respect to an ideal I, and let F ∈ A[w]
be a polynomial. If for some m ≥ 1 we have
F(0) ∈ Im and F′(0) ≡ 1 (mod I),
then there is an element α ∈ Im with F(α) = 0, and the recursion w0=0, wn+1=wn−F(wn)forn≥0
converges to α.

Comment: Hensel's Lemma can be extended to so called henselian pairs. U need a ring an an ideal in the Jacobson radical (for details see stacksproject henselian pairs)